# how to get events from json

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to only transfer this information through this way, but I know the standard ways to call this script, but I need to use this method.

```
$.get('events.json', function(data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data)
    setCookie("DATAevents",json,365);
});
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
  defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: getCookie("DATAevents")
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a cookie for this?? Anyway you can Just tell fullCalendar to read the URL directly: `events: "events.json"`. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: P s. If you really insist on using a cookie, the issues you've got are a) the Ajax request is asynchronous, so it hasn't finished by the time you are initialising the Calendar, so the cookie hasn't been set, and b) you'll need to parse the strinfigied data back into an array again. But as I said, it's really unnecessary to do this extra step. I can't see why it would be useful

Answer (score -2, accepted):

events: `$.parseJSON(getCookie("DATAevents"))`